# Federal Reserve OMO money goes to the Treasury?

Tags: central-banking, federal-reserve

If Federal Reserve performs open market operation by selling government securities then Fed gets money, who keeps that money? Does it go to Federal Reserve Deposit or the department of Treasury or somewhere else?

Comment: The question of what Fed does with all its profits was already asked and answered here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/37349/what-does-the-fed-do-with-their-profits

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you very much, Brian and muflon.